# How to connect TPA7297 S-GND and PW-GND

Tags: amplifier, integrated-circuit

I've just started making an amplifier for some speakers and I'm completely new to this and couldn't find any information in the documentation explaining it. So I just wanted to know if S-GND and PW-GND can be connected to a common ground back to the negative battery terminal? If not how would I go about connecting the grounds up?

Datasheet: http://www.st.com/web/en/resource/technical/document/datasheet/CD00001048.pdf

Thanks in advance :)
Will

*EDIT* I'm making the standalone version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, in most applications, the grounds can be tied together.

Note that you actually have all the documentation you need; the schematic in the datasheet for "stand-alone application" shows the grounds tied together.

Comment: The sample PCB layout also shows the S-GND and PW-GND connected together.

Comment: @PeterBennet however the current paths are seperated to minimize noise from ground currents

Comment: @crasic how would I go about separating the paths? Would they still both lead to the negative battery terminal?

Comment: @Will say your amp is running full tilt and sinking 1A to power ground. Even a fat wide trace would have a few milliohms of impedance. Meaning that there may be a potential difference of a few milli volts between the two ground pins on the IC. The two grounds are connected at one point and power currents are not routed through the signal ground path. Otherwise this noise would be induced onto the input (feedback) through the milli volt ground oscillations

Comment: On the pcb sample you can see that the trace from pin 8 (power ground) is routed around the board with a wide pour and the trace from pin 9 is a seperate trace and connected together closer to the header

Comment: @crasic ah ok thanks! The PCB sample in the data sheet is for use with a micro controller and I'm going to be using it standalone which is the schematic just above that. Would all of what you said still apply?

Answer (score 0):

As I suspect, the S-GND is the REF pin inside of the IC. You can easily check it out with your multi-meter. The internal input resistors from tda7297 is so useful to this conclusion. plus:s-gnd and gnd arent internally tied together